# Query for top N per group with pagination using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, top-n

I've searched for some answers on SO but none comes up with what I want to achieve, so here comes another question about top N per group.

**DB Structure**

Currently I have a Post table as followed:

```
post_id | post_title | post_text
```

and a Comment table as followed:

```
comment_id | post_id | comment_text | comment_date | ...
```

**Goal**

- I would like to get top n comments per post ordered by `comment_date` desc with support for pagination. Exactly n comments must be returned for each post if possible, e.g. if a post has 10 comments, 3 should be returned, if a post has 2 comments, only 2 can be returned.
- All comment fields should be returned.
- Only `post_id`, `post_title`, `post_text` need to be returned, but if we can return all fields that would be great.
- A post should appear only one time if possible, i.e. if it was in page 1 then in page 2 it would not be taken into account (please see example below). I think this is easier to achieve than allowing a post to appear several times.

**Example**

I have the following posts:

```
post_id | post_title | post_text
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
      1 | ...         | ...
      2 | ...         | ...
      3 | ...         | ...
      4 | ...         | ...
```

and following comments (ordered by `comment_date` desc, `date 12` is more recent than `date 11`):

```
comment_id | post_id | comment_date | ...
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
        12 |       1 | date 12      | ...
        11 |       2 | date 11      | ...
        10 |       2 | date 10      | ...
         9 |       2 | date 9       | ...
         8 |       3 | date 8       | ...
         7 |       1 | date 7       | ...
         6 |       4 | date 6       | ...
         5 |       2 | date 5       | ...
         4 |       2 | date 4       | ...
         3 |       1 | date 3       | ...
         2 |       1 | date 2       | ...
         1 |       1 | date 1       | ...
```

Let's say I have a limit of 6 comments per page, and `n` is 3. Expected results are:

```
Page 1:

comment_id | post_id | comment_date | ...
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
        12 |       1 | date 12      | ...
        11 |       2 | date 11      | ...
        10 |       2 | date 10      | ...
         9 |       2 | date 9       | ...
         7 |       1 | date 7       | ...
         3 |       1 | date 3       | ...

Page 2

comment_id | post_id | comment_date | ...
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
         8 |       3 | date 8       | ...
         6 |       4 | date 6       | ...
```

I've tried things similar to this: [Top N Per Group with Multiple Table Joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319643/top-n-per-group-with-multiple-table-joins) but if we order by `comment_date` desc there's no guarantee that there are exactly n results returned.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The code you're requesting, also fill the TODO I commented.

```
<?php

$start = isset($_GET['start']) ? $_GET['start'] : 0;
$max_record = 3;

$sql = "
  SELECT * FROM 
  post p INNER JOIN comment c
  ON p.post_id = c.post_id
  ORDER BY c.comment_date DESC LIMIT $start, $max_record
";

// TODO: create sql query.

$next = $start + $max_record;

?>

<p>SQL Start: <?php echo $start ?></p>
<p>SQL Max Record: <?php echo $max_record ?></p>

<a href="index.php?start=<?php echo $next ?>">Next</a>
```

I don't need to explain all things, even the unsecured script I provided, but the logic is there.

Comment: Thanks but this is not top n comments per post.

Comment: then use ORDER BY c.comment_date, c.post_id